# Integrar Columna Listado e inputs en datatable django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, bootstrap-4, django-forms

Estoy haciendo una planilla para recepción de equipos(o piezas) y para esto una tabla (DataTable Bootstrap) en la que necesito integrar la columna con listado desde un modelo (o `<select>`) y columnas de `<input>` para ingresar la cantidad de piezas ingresadas.
 La idea es tener el listado e ingresar las cantidades de cada pieza (o equipo)

No logro mostrar el listado en mi template, lo intente con un formset pero solo se ven los campos `<input>`.

[image: tabla]

Estos son mis modelos

```
class Recepcion(models.Model):
    nombre_empresa = models.ForeignKey('clientes.Clientes', to_field='nombre_empresa', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                       help_text='Ingrese nombre empresa', related_name='Empresa',
                                       default='Empresa')
    responsable = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, help_text="Ingrese nombre responsable",
                                   default='Nombre Responsable', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-fecha',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nombre_empresa)

class Tabla_recepcion(models.Model):
    recepcion = models.ForeignKey('Recepcion', related_name='tabla', verbose_name='Recepcion',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  default=0)
    recibidos = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-recibidos',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.recibidos)


class ListadoPiezas(models.Model):
    recepcion = models.ForeignKey('Recepcion', related_name='piezas', verbose_name='Recepcion',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  default=0)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-fecha',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.descripcion)
```

Archivo `forms.py`:

```
class RecepcionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recepcion
        exclude = ()

class Listado_recepcionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ListadoPiezas
        exclude = ()

class Tabla_recepcionForm(ModelForm):

    class meta:
        model = Tabla_recepcion
        exclude = ()

Tabla_recepcionFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Recepcion, Tabla_recepcion, form=Tabla_recepcionForm, extra=10, fields =['recibidos'], can_delete=True)
```

Mi vista:

```
class RecepcionCreate(CreateView):
model = Recepcion
fields = ['nombre_empresa', 'proyecto','responsable']

class RecepcionTabla_recepcionCreate(CreateView):
model = Recepcion
fields =  ['nombre_empresa', 'proyecto','responsable']
success_url = reverse_lazy('recepcion:recepcion-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super(RecepcionTabla_recepcionCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        data['recepcion'] = Tabla_recepcionFormSet(self.request.POST)
    else:
        data['recepcion'] = Tabla_recepcionFormSet()
    return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    recepcion = context['recepcion']
    with transaction.atomic():
        self.object = form.save()

            if recepcion.is_valid():
            recepcion.instance = self.object
            recepcion.save()
        else:
            context.update({
                'recepcion':recepcion
            })
            return self.render_to_response(context)

    return super(RecepcionTabla_recepcionCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Mi template:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    {{ recepcion.management_form|crispy }}
    {% for form in recepcion.forms %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">EQUIPOS</th>

                <th scope="col">RECIBIDOS</th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Codigo</th>
                <th scope="col">Piezas</th>
                <th scope="col">Cant</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
        {% endif %}
        <tr>
            <!-- NO LOGRO RESOLVER -->
                <th>Cod. Pieza</th>
                <th>Pieza</th>

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                <td>
                    {# Include the hidden fields in the forms #}
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                            {{ hidden }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                    {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                    {{ field }}
                </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Para resumir no logro mostrar la lista de piezas (o equipos) en la columna 1.
Por mas que lo pienso no lo logro dar con la forma de hacerlo, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cual es el problema, el problema es que no puedes visualizar el header "Listado" en fila de los headers "EQUIPOS"  y  "RECIBIDOS"? Explícate mejor.

Comment: Gracias por responder. No puedo hacer una tabla mezclando el listado (que no cambiará) y los campos input de cantidad. La idea sería escribir solo la cantidad de piezas o equipos que ingresan. No poner un formulario y tener escribir cada equipo o pieza y el número que ingresa.

Comment: Ok pero cual es el problema? no lo entiendo aun...

Comment: Que no logro hacer la tabla, que en una columna tenga un listado de tipos de equipos (que estarían en el modelo Listadopiezas) y en otra Columna La cantidad (quizás es muy básico, pero no lo logro). La imagen que dice listado ahí tendría que ir el listado. He probados varios formas y solo he logrado poner ahí los inputs de los campos del modelo ListadoPiezas.

Comment: Aver en la primera columna un listado de tipos de equipo, y en la segunda la cantidad de instancias de ListadoPiezas, relacionadas verdad? Pero a que modelo te refieres con "tipos de quipo"? Por otra parte el modelo, alias, "tipos de quipo" debería tener una relación con el modelo ListadoPiezas, que supongo que sera el modelo "Recepcion".

Comment: Si, inicialmente uso el modelo Recepcion como modelo padre, modelo hijo ListadoPiezas (pueden ser piezas o equipos) luego con un formset pero no logro poner en esa columna el listado de piezas (o equipos) si lograra ponerla como un listado fijo o los campos inputs  select.

Comment: OK entonces en la primera columna un listado de todas las instancias "Recepcion" y en la otra todas las instancias "ListadoPiezas" relacionadas con "Recepcion" verdad? Ademas según veo tu template, es renderisada por una vista CreateView o UpdateView, que modelo gestiona dicha vista?

Comment: Mejor actualiza tu pregunta con la vista que renderisa el template que mostraste.

Comment: Ok, lo acabo de modificar, gracias.

Comment: OK entonces en la primera columna un listado de todas las instancias "Recepcion" y en la otra todas las instancias "ListadoPiezas" relacionadas con "Recepcion" verdad? Por otra parte cual de esas 2 vistas renderisan el template que mostraste??

Comment: No, en la primera columna una lista de las piezas que estarían ingresadas en el modelo ListadoPiezas. En la segunda la cantidad que se guardaría en el modelo Tabla_recepcion. El modelo Recepcion se ingresaría la información de la empresa, (nombre_empresa, responsable, etc.)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105753/discussion-between-julio-cesar-and-pepex7).

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo resolví haciendo un foreignkey a un modelo de piezas en el campo pieza del modelo Tabla_recepcion. al mostrarlo en el template ese campo me muestra un select del listado(en este caso solo dos).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class Recepcion(models.Model):
nombre_empresa = models.ForeignKey('clientes.Clientes', to_field='nombre_empresa', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   help_text='Ingrese nombre empresa', related_name='Empresa',
                                   default='Empresa')
responsable = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, help_text="Ingrese nombre responsable",
                               default='Nombre Responsable', blank=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-fecha',)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.nombre_empresa)

class Tabla_recepcion(models.Model):
recepcion = models.ForeignKey('Recepcion', related_name='tabla', verbose_name='Recepcion',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              default=0)
Pieza = models.ForeignKey('piezas.Piezas', related_name='tablapiezas')
recibidos = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-recibidos',)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.recibidos)
```

Gracias @Julio Cesar por responder.